# Array isn't found in Android

Tags: android, listadapter

I have this bit of code:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.actiemenu, array));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

final String[] array = new String[] {
    "Ding", "AnderDing", "Nogeending", "laatseding"
};
```

the array in `R.layout.actiemenu`, array should be the Array created after that, at final `String[]` etc.

However, my Eclipse is giving me an error.
Does anyone know why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it **before** using it, so just swap the two statements:

```
final String[] array = new String[] {
    "Ding", "AnderDing", "Nogeending", "laatseding"
};

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.actiemenu, array));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```